# Get value of TO in cakephp 3 email layout

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to add this in the layout of the email I send out:
We sent this email to: `<a href="mailto:[EMAIL ADDRESS]">[EMAIL ADDRESS]</a>` where [EMAIL ADDRESS] needs to be replaced with the email address of the user this email is being sent to.

How do I get get value of TO in the layout?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just set this as a template variable using viewVars like this:

```
$Email = new Email();
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$Email->from(['me@me.com' => 'Me Name']);
$Email->to($sendTo);
$Email->subject('My Subject');
$Email->viewVars([
    'sendTo' => $sendTo,
]);
```

Then just access $sendTo in your template.

Comment: that works but I was hoping to find a way to get the value of TO variable, so that I dont have to set this var on each email.

Comment: I am not sure if you can access it. Try dumping $this in your email template and seeing if the Email object is in the scope. Personally I'd just set it if I needed it.

Comment: You could always set the email object itself in the viewVars and access it that way, but that doesn't seem like any improvement code-wise over what @systematical suggested.